# Pass values to custom handle bars helper, ember project

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am creating a test project in Ember to learn the frame work. However I have run in to a problem creating a custom helper to be used within a handle bars template. Basically I try to pass two parameters into a helper to return me a string.

The helper returns me a string as expected however declaring the parameters in the template does not seem to function as I would expect.

Here is my helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('backgroundImage', function(id, image) {
  result = id + 'some text' + image;
  new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
  return result;
});
```

Within my template I use the helper like this:

{{backgroundImage item.id item.blog_image.basename}}

However the it just "outputs item.id some text item.blog_image.basename" and not the values that they hold. i can output the value of item.id successfully if declared on its own.

I have probably miss understood something if any one could point me the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you post snippet of where you use handlebar function. The issue could be how the parameters are passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('backgroundImage', function(id, image) {
result = id + 'some text' + image;
new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
return result;
});
```

You have to use Embers extension of handlebars for it to work properly